# Get path of parent requiring file, Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory, require

Is it possible to get the location of the file which requires another file in Ruby?

I have a project where I spawn some processes and I would love to be able, in the code, to determine which file is the parent of the required file. This is nice when debugging.

Example:

```
#initial.rb:
require "./my_file.rb"
fork do
   require "./my_file2.rb"
end
```

-

```
#my_file.rb:

puts "Required from file: #{?????}"
```

-

```
#my_file2.rb:

require "./my_file.rb"
```

I would expect to get something like:

```
#=> Required from file: /path/to/initial.rb
#=> Required from file: /path/to/my_file2.rb
```

Comment: try `$0`.. in the file which you want to require. Read [this](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__). I can't test now, but try `puts "Required from file: #{$0}"`

Comment: You should use `require_relative` instead of `require "./my_file.rb"`. Whatever the solution is, it should also work with `require_relative`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Jacobs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23225708/676874) I ended with this redefinition of `require_relative` and `require`:

```
alias :old_require_relative :require_relative
def require_relative(arg)
  #~ puts caller.map{|x| "\t#{x}"}
  puts "%s requires %s" % [ caller.first.split(/:\d+/,2).first, arg]
  old_require_relative arg
end
alias :old_require :require
def require(arg)
  #~ puts caller.map{|x| "\t#{x}"}
  puts "%s requires %s" % [ caller.first.split(/:\d+/,2).first, arg]
  old_require arg
end
```

In a test test scenario with the following load sequence:

```
test.rb
+-  test1.rb
    +- test1_a.rb
+ test2.rb
```

The following calls

```
require './test1'
require './test2'
```

or

```
require_relative 'test1'
require_relative 'test2'
```

result in:

```
test.rb requires ./test1
C:/Temp/test1.rb requires test1_a
test.rb requires ./test2
```

You could also include the line of the requirement in the output.

Comment: I like the approach, however as I mentioned in @JacobLukas [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23225708/741850), there is issues when it comes to multiple processes. I would have to duplicate this several places. I would also need the the string in a variable accessible other places in the code, but that is easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to do this, but you can examine the call stack from `Kernel#caller`. You'll have to filter out require methods (especially if you use any libraries that override require).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why I never should do this? I guess it is not a common thing, but I am doing error-logging in sub-processes which potentially use the same libraries, and I need to distinguish them from each other. I could do PID-things, but it will complicate things severely to log which processes are started where and link these things together just to figure out which of my sub-processes are providing illegal data to some libraries.

Comment: If you used `logger` or a similar gem, you could set the pattern per-subprocess to include a unique identifier. Then your shared library could `def logger; Logging.logger[self]; end` and `logger.error('message')` etc. Or you could have your shared library take a parameter or something.